# Seeing String or binary data would be truncated when executing Stored Procedure MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MS SQL 2008, which compiles without error, but when go to execute the stored procedure I receive the error message 'String or binary data would be truncated'. Unfortunately, I am unable to trace where this is happening.

When I developed my Stored Procedure, I tested the query first, and it worked.

So, if anyone can show where and why this happening to me and how to solve it, I would be grateful:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Material_Validation]

@ValidType varchar(MAX),
@MaterialID varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE
@MessageReturn varchar(100);
SET @MessageReturn = NULL;

IF @ValidType = 'Primary'

Select TOP 1 Valid.StatusMessage
From
(Select MatID,'Property Not Completed' as StatusMessage
From dbo.Properties
WHERE DATALENGTH(ValueString)=0
UNION
Select PrpCount.MatID,'There not all Properties exist' as StatusMessage
From (Select Count(unkey) as unKeyCt, MatID
From Properties
Group By MatID
Having NOT Count(Cast(UnKey as Int)) = 19)AS PrpCount
UNION
SELECT Header,'Material does not exist' as StatusMessage
FROM Materials Item
Where NOT EXISTS (Select ID
FROM MatMaster Mat
WHERE MAT.ID= Item.HEAD)
UNION
SELECT Header,'Material(s) not Complete' as StatusMessage
FROM Materials
Where MatID IN (Select ID
FROM MatMaster
WHERE INC ='Y')) as Valid
Where Valid.MatID = @MaterialID;

IF @MessageReturn IS NOT NULL

UPDATE dbo.Mat_DEV
SET Inco ='Y',
User_Message = @MessageReturn
WHERE MatID = @MaterialID

ELSE
UPDATE dbo.Mat_DEV
SET User_Message = 'No Validation Errors'
WHERE MatID = @MaterialID
```

Comment: IS you table `ID` field really a `varchar(max)`? Do you know how implicit conversions work?

Comment: This seems strange to me - you never assign result of select to @ MessageReturn, and you filter using MaterialID after all checks, which are done on all records in tables just to be discarded afterwards. I think that you should repeat search condition in each subquery.

Answer (score 3):

String or binary data would be truncated only appears when you try and put a value in a box that isn't big enough to hold the value.

Now, you're only actually writing values in two places, so the candidates for your problem are:-

```
UPDATE dbo.Mat_DEV
SET Inco ='Y',
User_Message = @MessageReturn
WHERE MatID = @MaterialID
```

..or..

```
UPDATE dbo.Mat_DEV
SET User_Message = 'No Validation Errors'
WHERE MatID = @MaterialID
```

Check the column definitions for both these columns ( Inco and User_Message ).  My guess is that one is too small to hold the value you want to set.

Comment: +1 And I doubt it's INCO because you can't have a string column with a length that won't accommodate `'Y'`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that column User_Message does not have enough length

Comment: Sorry, questioned closed! It was another field throwing an error, but the error message was not pointing in the correct place

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

When I executed the stored proc directly, everything worked as it should.
When I called the same proc from ASP.NET, I got 'String or binary data would be truncated'...

Finally I realized the culprit was a varchar(20) field with the default value 'suser_sname()'... in SQL Management Studio the user name was short, from ASP.NET it was more than 20 chars... A simple CAST solved the problem. :)